# Inline r code chunk r studio visual editor

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I have a problem finding the option to create an **inline** r code chunk in an r-markdown document in r-studios visual editor. In the normal editor the syntax is **`` ` ``r variable_here`` ` ``**, but that does not work in the visual editor.

I could switch to the normal editor to insert the chunk, but in my experience switching back and forth changes the document and things in the document breaks unintentionally.

Comment: For me doesn't work too, or I don't know something...

Answer (score 0):

According to this help-guide you just have to press the command ⌘ and 'D' key together as a short-cut. It seems to work.

https://rstudio.github.io/visual-markdown-editing/technical.html